# how do i convert my series object into string? i think thats the prblem

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, data-science, bert-language-model

i have saved my dataset in two lists

> hi_list=df['hindi_lyrics'] and
> en_list=df['english_lyrics']

the output for these list are (en_lyrics)

```
 Mere ishaare pe
1       Tak dhina dhin naacha jo
2       Twitter pe trend ho gaya
3          Hey Nashik ke dhol pe
4      Dhan dhana dhan naacha to
```

HERE i put my data for word alignment using multilingual BERT

```
   sent_src, sent_tgt = hi_list.strip().split(), en_list.strip().split()
    token_src, token_tgt = [tokenizer.tokenize(word) for word in sent_src], [tokenizer.tokenize(word) for word in sent_tgt]
    wid_src, wid_tgt = [tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x) for x in token_src], [tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x) for x in token_tgt]
    ids_src, ids_tgt = tokenizer.prepare_for_model(list(itertools.chain(*wid_src)), return_tensors='pt', model_max_length=tokenizer.model_max_length, truncation=True)['input_ids'], tokenizer.prepare_for_model(list(itertools.chain(*wid_tgt)), return_tensors='pt', truncation=True, model_max_length=tokenizer.model_max_length)['input_ids']
    sub2word_map_src = []
    for i, word_list in enumerate(token_src):
      sub2word_map_src += [i for x in word_list]
    sub2word_map_tgt = []
    for i, word_list in enumerate(token_tgt):
      sub2word_map_tgt += [i for x in word_list]
```

here is the error i get
**

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'

should i convert my object into a different atrribute ...what should i do

Comment: Did you  forget `.str` accessor  ? `hi_list.str.strip().str.split()` ?

Comment: ohh yes i did thank you soo much But this is the error now..`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'` this is for the second line of the code (tokenizer)